# Tags when different products share same name

Tags: support, tags

I want to be able to ask questions about [Tilt](https://tilt.dev/), a Kubernetes user interface, and tag them with `Tilt`.  However, the tag [tilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilt) is already in use for another project with the same name. So if I tag my question with [tilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilt) it will be included in a collection of questions that are not related.

How should this situation be best resolved?

Comment: Maybe `[kubernetes-tilt]` ? Some `[kubernetes-something]` already exist

Comment: Thanks, I can try `[kubernetes-tilt]`. And then suggest renaming `[tilt]`to `[ruby-tilt]` to avoid mix-ups.

Comment: I guess retaging `[tilt]` should be treated in another post effectively. Retagging an existing one is more sensitive than creating a new one